# Anime where the main character has a red eagle-like form

Tags: story-identification, anime

The main character in this anime has a red eagle-like form. Additionally, another character possesses the ability to transform into a wolf-like creature, the character who can transform into a wolf-like creature has two forms: one bipedal and one quadrupedal. Can anyone tell me the title of this anime?

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Answer (score 2):

Might this be [*Digimon Frontier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Frontier) (original airing early 2000s depending on where you lived, although some regions only got it much later)?

There are more than the two characters you mention, but the "lead" characters are mostly Takuya who has multiple transformations:

- red-colored
- knight-looking
- vaguely fire-themed
- several of them have bird-like wings

And Koji who has multiple transformations that are:

- blue-colored
- wolf-themed
- one of which is quadrupedal